# Asp.net partial view in a view not being recognized from within a view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, view, partial-views

I have created a little blog and and I have a view and have embedded a partial view in it.
The embedded partial view is the 'like' button(link).

It appears in the view but when I click the 'like' anchor, it does not go into the partial view.
I have an alert and console log and they do not appear.

When I click it, the # is appended to the URL.

What am I doing wrong?
Also, I want to reference a value from a button in the parent view.
I try: var blogId = $(this).attr("data-id");

Is that correct?

[image]

--- The view - the parent.

```
@model GbngWebClient.Models.BlogPublishedByBlogIdVM

<h2 class="page-header"><span class="blogtitle">@Session["BlogTitle"]</span></h2>

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutUser.cshtml";
}

@if (ViewBag.errormessage != null)
{
    <p class="alert alert-danger" id="errorMessage">@ViewBag.errormessage</p>
}

<br />

<div>
    <a href="@Url.Action("LoadDropdownBlogCategorysInBlogsPublished", "BlogPublished")">Return To 
Select a Blog</a>
</div>
<br />

@if (Model != null)
{
<div class="panel panel-default toppanel">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BlogPublishedByBlogId.CreatedDateTime)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.BlogPublishedByBlogId.CreatedDateTime, new { @class = "form-control", @disabled = "disabled" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BlogPublishedByBlogId.ModifiedDateTime)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.BlogPublishedByBlogId.ModifiedDateTime, new { @class = "form-control", @disabled = "disabled" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />

        <div class="row">
            <div>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.BlogPublishedByBlogId.BlogContent, new { @class = "form-control blogContent", @disabled = "disabled" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />

        <div class="row">
            <div>
                @Html.Partial("_BlogLikeOrDislike")
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />

        <div class="panel-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary Comment" data-id="@Model.BlogPublishedByBlogId.BlogId" value="Comment">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment" aria-hidden="true"></span> Get Comment(s)
            </button>
        </div>

        @* The area dynamically built. It will hold the partial view - BlogPublished/_Comments.cshtml which also holds the partial view - BlogPublished/_CommentReplys.cshtml. *@
        @* The partial view is shown after the 'Get Comment(s)' button above is clicked. *@

        @* Add comment area. *@
        <div id="@string.Format("{0}_{1}","commentsBlock", @Model.BlogPublishedByBlogId.BlogId)" style="border: 1px solid #f1eaea; background-color: #eaf2ff;">
            @*Centering the button with in-line CSS. *@
            <div class="AddCommentArea" style="margin-left: 30%;  margin-bottom: 5px; margin-top: 8px;">
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                <input type="text" id="@string.Format("{0}_{1}", "comment", @Model.BlogPublishedByBlogId.BlogId)" class="form-control" placeholder="Add a comment..." style="display: inline;" />
                @* Button. *@
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary addComment" data-id="@Model.BlogPublishedByBlogId.BlogId"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")

@section Scripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Has ajax calls to controller methods.
     });
</script>
}
```

--- The small partial view - _BlogLikeOrDislike.cshtml.

```
<div>
<a href="#" class="LikeOrDislike" style="margin-left: 5px; font-weight: bold; font-size: 13px;">Like</a>
</div>

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")

@section Scripts
{
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert('here.');
        console.log('here.');

        $('.LikeOrDislike').on('click', function () {
            // HOW TO REFERENCE THE PARENTS VALUE?.
            var blogId = $(this).attr("data-id");

            alert('here. blogid from parent: ' + blogId);

            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '@Url.Action("SetBlogLikeCountOrDislikeCount", "BlogPublished")',
                data: { blogId: blogId },
                success: function (response) {

                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert("Critical Error: something is wrong in the call to SetBlogLikeCountOrDislikeCount! Status: " + xhr.status + ". Error: " + thrownError.toString() + ". Response Text: " + xhr.responseText);
                }
            })
        });
    });
</script>
}
```

Comment: This is more like a jquery question. BTW: Your partial is kind of messy; you should move bundles-stuff to parent view or layout.

Comment: If I move the partial view's JavaScript code to the parent, it works. I,e the DIV is the only thing that is in the partial view now. Can't a partial view have it's own JavaScript to fire off a controller method? I would want that so I can REUSE this partial view in any parent view.

Comment: You may of course have js in your partials, what I think is messy, is @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval") inside a partial along-side with specific code. That should be in page or in layout. You can create a separate partial with the @Scripts.Render-stuff and use that in your e.g. page.

Comment: Ok..I removed that @Scripts.Render but that did not fix my issue either way. It is not recognizing the JS in the partial. The only way to get it to work was to move the JavaScript to the parent.

Comment: If you press F12 in chrome and have a look at the Console, you will probably see som js-errors that explains the problem.

Comment: I did that but none stood out. I will send a screen shot.

Comment: My guess is that some js-lib is not loaded when using partial. Try to replace $(document).ready(function () { with document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {

Comment: If you look at the HTML source, you will more easy spot the error when you have a look at the ordering of how js is included in your page. All js-code should be at the very bottom of your page, and in correct order. First libs, then your code. So,if you split your partial into one with GUI, and one with js, that would be better.

Comment: Nice things finally worked. This question is kind of edge case with little use for others. Maybe just delete the question along with your answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the partial view, I had to remove the:

```
   @section Scripts
   {
   }
```

surrounding the JavaScript

and just have:

```
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery").
```

Without it, I was getting: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined.
The library was not being brought in.

Per suggested instead of:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
```

and

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

I could just use:

```
 document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function ()
```

and no

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

So now the script section is being executed.

Now, to pass a value from the parent view to the partial view, I had to create a model in the parent view:

```
 @{
    double parentBlogId = @Model.BlogPublishedByBlogId.BlogId;
 }
```

and pass it as:

```
<div class="row">
     <div>
         @Html.Partial("_BlogLikeOrDislike", parentBlogId)
     </div>
</div>
```

and receive it in the partial view's click function:

```
   var parentBlogId  = @Model;
```